# Windows 2008 R2 Task Scheduler triggered an event for unknown reasons

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, task-scheduler

Today I arrived at the office only to find that a task, which was scheduled to trigger at 5:30PM EST each Friday, had triggered on its own at 6:01AM EST this morning. I checked the event logs as well as the task schedule log and all of the evidence points to a timed trigger starting this task with the correct credentials, however the task history reports the task has not been triggered since last Friday when it ran to completion successfully. I do not have this task set to random start times or start if missed.  This is the first time I have observed this happen in the Windows Task Scheduler and want to know if anyone else has come across this, why it happened and how to fix it?

Comment: That's very strange. I have a ton of scheduled tasks on many boxes and have never seen something like that.

Comment: Right, I've never come across this either.  I've saved the application, security, system, task scheduler, and task history logs for further analysis.

The task calls a Perl script which queries a database server for a list of users.  If users exist, it issues a command to the server to disconnect the users, waits for all users to be disconnected, then starts an application which queries and analyzes the data for the next business week and once the analysis is complete, exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tracking down the scheduled process within the Task Scheduler log I found that a process had been created and placed in an incorrect location

> \Microsoft\Windows\CertificateServicesClient\"taskname"

instead of in the correct location

> \"taskname"